# Change Log View to Charts in Samples of Google Fit App Sample

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Can someone guide me,How to change Log View output to Charts like Official Google fit app.
Can any one helpme to get code samples.
Right Now i am getting logview output.
[image]

I want to add Chart View as

[image]